# How to check if my dynamic array is empty in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, data-structures

I've a dynamic array like this one:

```
typedef struct
{
    int *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Vector;
```

and I need to check if it's empty. At first, I thought, if I didn't initiate it, then the size should be = 0, but it seems like it's a random number. When I initiate it, all the initiates arrays are = 0, but then, it doesn't mean it's empty, because it has be initiated... Any ideas what should I do?

Here's also my initiation function:

```
int createVector(Vector *v, size_t initialSize)
{
    if (v->size != 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int i;
        v->array = (int*)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
        v->used = 0;
        v->size = initialSize;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show how `v` was allocated. If it was allocated via `malloc` or is a stack variable then it is not initialised automatically and contains garbage as you have found. So just initialise its `array` field to be NULL (probably best to just `memset` the whole struct to be 0 or use `calloc` instead of `malloc` which does that zeroing for you). And checking that field would tell you whether you need to `malloc` the array or not.

Comment: My "v" is in the main.c as: Vector v;

Comment: Then it is a stack variable and is not initialised automatically. So just explicitly intialise it as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a `Vector` variable before you can use it.  You can't assume it is initialized automatically, you have to do it explicitly.

When it has no elements, you should set its `size` and `used` fields to 0 and its `array` field to `NULL`.

If you want `createVector()` to perform the initialization then you can't make any assumptions about the current state of the `Vector`, just initialize it unconditionally, and hope the user never passes in a initialized `Vector` that already has elements in it:

```
int createVector(Vector *v, size_t initialSize)
{
    v->array = NULL;
    v->used = 0;
    v->size = 0;

    if (initialSize > 0)
    {
        v->array = (int*) malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
        if (!v->array)
            return 0;
        v->size = initialSize;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

```
Vector v;
int i = createVector(&v, 10);
```

On the other hand, if you want `createVector()` to ignore a `Vector` that has elements in it, you have to initialize it beforehand so it has a valid state you can check for:

```
void initVector(Vector *v)
{
    v->array = NULL;
    v->used = 0;
    v->size = 0;
}

int createVector(Vector *v, size_t initialSize)
{
    if ((v->array) || (v->size != 0))
        return 0;

    v->used = 0;

    if (initialSize > 0)
    {
        v->array = (int*) malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
        if (!v->array)
            return 0;
        v->size = initialSize;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

```
Vector v;
int i;

initVector(&v);
i = createVector(&v, 10); // OK
i = createVector(&v, 20); // error, already created
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what if the user wants the first element to be 0? Because if I understand, then NULL = 0? At least that's what it seems to be for me.

OR should I maybe make another struct, which would had a *HEAD in it? And the head would have NULL, unless it shows to the first array?

Comment: @Tripper: it is a little unclear what you are asking. By "*first element*" are you referring to the `array` field itself in the struct?  An array can be allocated with 0 elements and thus have a non-NULL pointer to it.  But it doesn't really make sense to allocate a 0-element array, that is just a waste of memory.  Setting the `array` field to NULL makes it pretty clear that the array is empty since it is not even allocated. Beyond that, you can certainly set the **value** of the first element *inside the array* to 0, but the `size` would have to be >0 in order to access that element.

Comment: Yes, I ment the array. And yeah, that's what I wanted to know. So allocating 0 is just waste of memory. Thank you! :)